# How to conditional count in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table like below:

**Q:** How can I count all `Female Undergraduate` or `Male Diploma` ? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place these formulas somewhere

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B25,"Male",C2:C25,"Diploma")
=COUNTIFS(B2:B25,"Female",C2:C25,"Undergraduate")
```

Answer (score 3):

For multi-conditional counting use `COUNTIFS` function, e.g. to count Female Undergraduates

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,"Female",C:C,"Undergraduate")`

COUNTIFS requires Excel 2007 or later version